# Redirect from http to https using .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect my wordpress website from http to https so I am using below code in `.htaccess`. But it is giving me error 'The page isn’t redirecting properly'.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mywebsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

I already enabled SSL in `wp-config` file and it is working fine if I go from one page to another page. I am getting issue only when I copy paste any `http` link in browser then it is not redirecting to `https`.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: @anubhava ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: No, chrome dev tool shows each & every redirect before `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following, also ensure that you have no caching plugins that may be enabled.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: Have you updated your site URL's in the database to include https? It sounds like WordPress is trying to redirect the https back to http? and therefore redirect looping.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect Http to https:

```
  # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
```